# Calling wcf service from another WCF service hangs the call

Tags: c#, wcf

I have several services running.  I can call everyone from a client application.  I am trying to call into one service from another service (same application - they are hosted in an application for testing but can also run as a windows service).

The call I use to do this from the client is simply create the factory and CreateChannel and then open.
When I do this in a service trying to connect to another service I don't get an error it just hangs and eventually times out.  I have no idea what is wrong.

I am using net.pipe://localhost/test as my endpoint and transport.

Answer (score 0):

This was really stupid but (and) I will post the issue to help others that may run into this...
All of my service was running single threaded so when I called into another service it was blocking itself.  I now start my threads on backgroundworker threads and the issue is gone.

Thanks